# How to close Subprocess that runs other Subprocess on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, process, subprocess, shutdown

I am facing the following problem and can't solve it.

1. **A** runs **B** as `multiprocessing.Process()`
2. **B** runs **C** as `subprocess.run()`
3. **A** terminates **B** by `multiprocessing.Process.terminate()`
4. Expected: **B** and **C** are terminated
   Result: **B** is terminated and **C** runs in background

**Important additional information**

- **A**, **B**, **C** are programs
- **A** is my program that **I develop**
- **B**, **C** are external programs **not developed by me** and I have **no control**
  of
- Solution must work on  **Windows**

**Question**  Does anyone have any solution or know if it isn't possible?

Following code describes my problem on example:

```py
# main.py - Process A
# Runs Process B
import multiprocessing
from Manager import manager
from time import sleep

def main():
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=manager)

    proc.start()
    print("[MAIN] Process going sleep")
    sleep(3)
    print("[MAIN] Process is awake now. Beginning to terminate")
    proc.terminate()
    proc.join()
    print("[MAIN] Process Manager terminated.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```py
# Manager.py - Process B
# Cannot change any code
# Runs process C
import subprocess

def manager():
    print("[MANAGER] START")
    subprocess.run(["python", "sleepery.py"])
    print("[MANAGER] Terminated")
```

```py
# sleepery.py - Process C
# Cannot change any code
from time import sleep

def sleeper():
    """This process prints info every two seconds for 8"""
    for _ in range(4):
        sleep(2)
        print(f"[SLEEPER] prints!")
    print("[SLEEPER] ends")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sleeper()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[MAIN] Process going sleep
[MANAGER] START
[SLEEPER] prints!
[MAIN] Process is awake now. Beginning to terminate
[MAIN] Process Manager terminated.
[SLEEPER] prints! 
[SLEEPER] prints!
[SLEEPER] prints!
[SLEEPER] ends
```

**WANTED OUTPUT**

```
[MAIN] Process going sleep
[MANAGER] START
[SLEEPER] prints!
[MAIN] Process is awake now. Beginning to terminate
[MAIN] Process Manager terminated.
```

**My research** 
The only thing that works is to kill all python processes by `taskkill`
But it isn't exactly *graceful*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Job object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects), this allows you to group all child processes in this job and kill them all in a single step.

Answer (score 0):

Anders's answer goes right into the point.
Here is refactored **main.py** to use Job Objects

```py
# main.py - Process A
# Runs Process B
import multiprocessing

import win32api
from Manager import manager
from time import sleep
import time
import win32job
import win32con

def main():
    jobHandle = win32job.CreateJobObject(None, "")
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=manager)
    proc.start()
    # Get handle to process and assign process to job object
    handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, True, proc.pid)
    win32job.AssignProcessToJobObject(jobHandle, handle)
    print("[MAIN] Process going sleep")
    sleep(3)
    print("[MAIN] Process is awake now. Beginning to terminate")
    win32job.TerminateJobObject(jobHandle, 0)
    print("[MAIN] Process Manager and his kids terminated.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then **output**:

```bash
> python .\main.py
[MAIN] Process going sleep
[MANAGER] START
[SLEEPER] prints!
[MAIN] Process is awake now. Beginning to terminate
[MAIN] Process Manager and his kids terminated.
```